# Declare and set database names to copy tables from 1 database to another

Tags: sql-server

I'm copying multiple tables from one database to another and I wish to `declare/set` the `source_db_name` and `destination_db_name` as variables. I've tried using the following without success

```
DECLARE @DESTINATION_DB_NAME char(30)
SET @DESTINATION_DB_NAME = 'DDB'

DECLARE @SOURCE_DB_NAME char(30)
SET @SOURCE_DB_NAME = 'SDB'
```

To then use:

```
CREATE TABLE [DESTINATION_DB_NAME].[dbo].[DESTINATION_TBL]

INSERT INTO [DESTINATION_DB_NAME].[dbo].[DESTINTION_TBL]
FROM  [SOURCE_DB_NAME].[dbo].[SOURCE_TBL]
```

Comment: There many tools to support such operation. No sure if you must use script or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare a dynamic query for this like below:

```
DECLARE @DESTINATION_DB_NAME varchar(30)
SET @DESTINATION_DB_NAME = 'DDB'

DECLARE @SOURCE_DB_NAME varchar(30)
SET @SOURCE_DB_NAME = 'SDB'


DECLARE @SQL  varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ['+@DESTINATION_DB_NAME + '].[dbo].[DESTINATION_TBL] INSERT INTO ['+ @DESTINATION_DB_NAME + '].[dbo].[DESTINTION_TBL] FROM [' + @SOURCE_DB_NAME + '].[dbo].[SOURCE_TBL]'  
print @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```